# WSO2 api manager https endpoint rewritten with port

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have defined an api in WSO2 api manager that has an endpoint in HTTPS (ie https://myapi/1.0/).
When a resource of my api is called, WSO2 call this endpoint https://myapi:443/1.0/.
Is it a way to remove this port and force WSO2 to call the original endpoint definition ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

443 is the default port[1] https  , so if you don't specify the port, any system will resolve it to default port

1.http://www.howtogeek.com/233383/why-was-80-chosen-as-the-default-http-port-and-443-as-the-default-https-port/

Comment: Thanks, I know that. But I want to know if there is a possibility with WSO2 to not add this port in the URL.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing when having those default ports ?